# How to create a iAd banner?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iad, banner

I'm still a noob developper and I just finished my little game and now I want to integrate AdBanner.

With the code bellow the banner appear and disappear instantly. I tried on another ViewController/GameScene and the banner appear and stay. I can't understand the problem.

My Game is under gravity. It is to shoot falling objects from the bottom of the screen.

Someone can help me ?

Here my GameViewController code  :

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import iAd

var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")


class GameViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    var skView = self.originalContentView as SKView
    var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.showsPhysics = false

    let turbulence = SKFieldNode.turbulenceFieldWithSmoothness(0.1, animationSpeed: 0.1)
    scene.addChild(turbulence)
    let noise = SKFieldNode.turbulenceFieldWithSmoothness(0.4, animationSpeed: 0.1)
    scene.addChild(noise)

    skView.presentScene(scene)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: You can check it on apple developer reference [http://developer.apple.com/iAd](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the iAd framework into the project. Then link it into your file with:

```
import iAd
```

Then you add this line of code whenever you want the ad to come onto the screen:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

This will automatically give you an add at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks I tried but it doesn't work : `EXC_BREAKPOINT`Where have I to add the second line code ? Thank you for your help

Comment: If you want it to come in when the view loads in you add the line in viewDidLoad().

Comment: I updated the question with my code. I still have the same error

Comment: You shouldn't even have to add the bannerView and the hiding. When I implement iAd I just import the file and add the line of code in my answer

Comment: I find where was my error. My gamescene was set up in another method in my GameViewController. So I don't have the breakpoint anymore. Unfortunately the banner doesn't appear... I edit my code again

Comment: When I tried it I just added the line I posted in my viewDidLoad() method and it showed up at the bottom.

Comment: I completely add my gameViewController code. I add a screenshot of my game with this code. No banner appears :(

Comment: I'm not sure. When I run my test it pops up after about 7 seconds.

Comment: My timer start at 30s. on the screen shot it's 17. So more than 7s. I'm trying directly on my iphone

Comment: I tried your code on my presentationview and it works. I can't understand why on my gameView it doesn't works. Actually I suppose the banner appear and disappear instantly. I edited my question to find help...